# Entity Framework 6 update of table takes very long for one of the records

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In an ASP.NET MVC application using EF 6 with SQL Server, when updating a table to change one particular row, it takes a very long time (10 minutes plus, and only sometimes the change ultimately gets through).

However, using the same web page to update any other row in the same table, it's immediate. Also, when I open SQL Server Management Studio and use an update query to update that specific row, it's immediate as well, and so is changing the row through the Edit Top 200 Records functionality.

The table in question holds various statuses used for keeping track record processing (there are 23 records in the table). It has an `ID` which is the primary key (only column referenced by other tables), and it has `Name` and `Description` columns. I'm changing the description in the example above.

As the row I'm changing is for the OK status, which is the most used one, the only thing I could come up with is that somehow all records referencing this status are also updated or at least checked, but besides the fact that this is not exactly how relational databases work, that would also still not explain why the update is immediate when I use a query in SSMS. Hence my assumption that this is somehow caused by EF ding or checking something in the background.

Unfortunately this is on a production environment where I have very limited access or debugging options. On the TEST and ACCEPTANCE environments it is working normally.

Any ideas what might cause this behavior?

Thanks, Patrick

Comment: Are there any persisted views or indexes which depend on the column which gets updated?

Comment: What does *your code* do? EF runs disconnected and uses optimistic concurrency so the only way updating would block is if some *other* connection kept a lock on that row for a long time, eg by starting a long-running transaction or executing a report that takes 10 minutes to complete, thus locking all rows it reads for that long. If your own code uses transactions, you have a bug.

Comment: `still not explain why the update is immediate when I use a query in SSMS.` it does. You can't update a row that's locked for reading or updating, unless you use SNAPSHOT isolation. You wouldn't want the value of `OK` to change to `Cool` in the middle of a report that takes 10 minutes to complete after all. If nothing else uses that row, UPDATEs complete immediately. If not, they'll have to wait until the row is no longer in use

Comment: _still not explain why the update is immediate when I use a query in SSMS._ Here's another explanation: it could be a bad plan caching issue (e.g.: parameter sniffing) as well. SSMS uses `SET ARITHABORT ON` by default, whereas nearly every client library uses `SET ARITHABORT OFF` by default, so SSMS is basically guaranteed not to use the same cached plans that the application(s) are using even for byte-for-byte identical queries. Have a read through [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for taking the time to try and help me out here. I managed to get some debug messages in the controller code, and it turns out that the controller method called by the page submit is not even hit most of the time. I don't see any differences in the generated html between the view for the offending record and the views of any of the other records, so it still strikes me as weird that the same page seems to act differently with only 1 specific record, but at least now I know I have to look for the answer in ASP/MVC, and not EF or the db.

Thanks again!